# Need Help Styling Drupal 6 Calendar

Tags: drupal, calendar

I have a customer that wants to display his manufacturing production schedule on his Drupal 6 website.

Currently the customer has the production schedule in an Excel file, and each production job is color coded depending on the type of project.

I have created a Content Type and plan on using the Calendar module to display the content.  The Content Type has a field called "Job Type" (field_job_type) which contains all of the type codes.

In order for this to be successful, I need to color code each Job (Job Name, Type, Date, and Location) according to the color code in the Excel file.  However, I am kind of stumped on how to do it.

If anyone can provide some assistance, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Drupal 6 calendar module has this functionality, but you'll need to link the type via taxonomy. I am currently stuck at the very same point - can't apply the color codes. I hope this will be somehow helpful - https://drupal.org/node/855224#comment-3721632